# Add filter in the list of apps

Tags: settings, tablet

**ALCATEL 8088Q 3T10** tablet.

In the **SETTINGS** of this tablet in **SPECIAL APP ACCESS** there is a **BATTERY OPTIMISATION** list. In this list one can either see all apps or apps which are not optimised.

In other words, there are only 2 filters in this list viz 1. **NOT OPTIMISED** 2. **ALL** **APPS**.

Now what I need is a 3rd filter viz 3. **OPTIMIZED** so that I can view the list of only those apps which are optimised.

Is there any way (eg through the developer mode in settings) to add this 3rd filter ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.

Those options are built into the system and there exists no way to add an "Optimise" filter. But yes, I do understand your requirement.